# C: Having a global variable why the value is not saved when it is called in main function,

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming. In my main.c file I declare a global variable and initialize it to 0.  This variable will run in pthread function and there it should be updated so I can reuse it main function again.

```
static int gResult = 0; 

void* pthreadTask(){
  gResult= readValue(); // It gives 1. gResult should be 1 now.
                        // But it gives 0.
}

int main(){
   if(gResult == 1)printf("Passed test");
}
```

Comment: That function is the incorrect format for pthreads. How do you create the thread? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Incomplete code snippet[s], we can't guess the problem.

Comment: Possibily data race.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like is that the thread is created but it is not scheduled immediately. So, the thread doesn't run any code and before that you check the value of your global variable. Try checking the variable after your thread has finished running. So, check the variable after pthread_join(). Do not use pthread_exit(). Try the following code (I tried it and it works):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

static int gRes0 = 0;

static void *pthreadTask5(void* ctx)
{

    gRes0 = 1;
    printf("Value of gRes0 in thread = %d\n", gRes0);

}

int main(void)
{

    pthread_t pt;

    pthread_create(&pt, NULL, pthreadTask5, NULL);

    // join pthread.
    pthread_join(pt, NULL);

    printf("Value of gRes0 in main = %d\n", gRes0);

    return 0;

}
```